# Error "Out of memory" vb6

Tags: vb6

I have an app that runs well in the IDE, but wont run in the exe form. I have logging, so the app generates the out of memory error at the login form

```
  Login.Show vbModal
  Unload Login
```

In the login load subroutine, this is the code i have there.

```
m_lsLoginState = Failed
Me.Height = 1815
```

does anyone have any idea what could be causing th error. The  m_isLoginState is an enum variable

```
Public Enum LoginStates
    Failed
    Succeed
    Quit
End Enum
```

Comment: Post the smallest amount of code which causes this error, if possible.

Comment: the error happens at the `Login.SHow vbModal` in the Main subroutine of a module

Comment: Is there code in the login form that is run when it loads, or is activated?

Comment: @Beaner yes, i pasted it above. value is assigned to a variable, and then the height of the form is changed

Comment: Is m_lsLoginState as private variable in the form and what is Failed?

Comment: @Beaner I edited the question, please look at it.

Comment: It is not possible that the code supplied raises an Out of Memory Error. Start with a new project and paste in the code line for line until you get the error.

Comment: @Dabblernl theoretically, that is true, but practically, i need to find out why it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the cause and solution to the problem

It happens that am using manifest file added to the project resources so that when the app compiles, it will show the controls in windows theme.

I then notice that the main form frmMain had this initialization, whereas the login form is shown first.

```
m_Shell32 = LoadLibrary("Shell32.dll")
Call InitCommonControls
```

what puzzled me is that the compiled executable has been working like this for a while without any problem.

After much tweaking, i got another error `system error &H80070583 (-2147023485)`, when the app executable was launched. This error indicates that it is a manifest problem, leading me to the solution

I solve the problem by moving the code above to the initialization of the login form

Thanks for all you help

Comment: Quite correct, Smith.  Apologies for my careless post, and thanks for pointing it out.